# Select query on a model returns empty collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Firstly, I have went through a similar question here, and I should have asked my question there; however, I am a new user and lack sufficient reputation points to comment. Hence, I apologize to have asked this question here.

I have a select query using Eloquent Model which includes a dynamically created column using DB::raw method. The problem I am facing is that it returns an empty collection even when there is relevant data in the database table to be displayed.

Also, when I ran this query in mysql, it returns the required output.

```
$geocodes = Geocode::select(
 DB::raw("zipcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                             cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
                             cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) +
                             sin( radians(?) ) *
                             sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                   ) AS distance"))
 ->having("distance", "<", "?")
 ->orderBy("distance")
 ->setBindings([$latitude, $longitude, $latitude, $radius])
 ->get();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query it produces to ensure it's as you're expecting? If you use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` you can see the query generated.

Comment: Yes it does. This is the query I got:
select zipcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *\n
                             cos( radians( latitude ) ) *\n
                             cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) +\n
                             sin( radians(?) ) *\n
                             sin( radians( latitude ) ) )\n
                   ) AS distance from `geocodes` having `distance` < ? order by `distance` asc

Comment: Also, when i ran this query in mysql, it returns the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I wasn't able to figure out as to why I was getting any empty collection with the above mentioned Eloquent query; however, as the converted query was producing the required result I used the entire raw query to get an array of results.

However I would really appreciate if someone could answer as to why the original query was returning an empty collection.

```
$geocodes = DB::select(DB::raw("select zipcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                         cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
                         cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?) ) +
                         sin( radians(?) ) *
                         sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
               ) AS distance from geocodes having distance <= ? order by distance"), [$lat, $long, $lat, $radius]);
```